# Extract key.jks and trust.jks from .kdb file

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, jks

We have a key.kdb file, contents of which I can browse using ikeyman tool(ibm),

I need to know how I can extract key.jks and trust.jks of one of the personal certs from the kdb,

I require the jks files to populate in the IBM Mq explorer for connectivity.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command to extract from kdb to jks:

```
runmqckm -cert -export -db key.kdb -target key.jks -stashed -target_type jks -label "certLabel"
```